How to setup a unit test for atlaskit component UserPicker using react testing library & JEST?
I am using a atlaskit component UserPicker in my JIRA Custom UI application.
I need to setup a unit test for it. But I cannot find a way to 'expect' the component on the screen.
I have tried using ByRole, ById and ByLabel to expect the UserPicker but it didn't work.
It would be really helpful if someone can me guide me on how to setup a unit test for atlaskit components like UserPicker.
